# MySQL join vs union

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have a single table, `message`, with the columns `id` (primary key), `parent_id` (foreign key to self), `owner_id` (creator user ID) and `message` (the actual message).

I'm now trying to retrieve all columns that are either owned by a specific `owner_id` or that have a `parent_id` pointing to another record which is owned by a specific `owner_id`.

I've successfully done this thus:

```sql
select * from message m1
left join message m2 on m1.id = m2.parent_id
where m1.owner_id = 1;
```

However, I get the result as this (`m2` columns added on the right side):

```
id  parent_id   owner_id    message         id      parent_id   owner_id    message
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   NULL        1           First message   3       1           2           Third message
1   NULL        1           First message   4       1           2           Fourth message
2   NULL        1           Second message  NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

... when I want it like this (a simple list of all unique matching columns, order is unimportant):

```
id  parent_id   owner_id    message
------------------------------------------
1   NULL        1           First message
3   1           2           Third message
4   1           2           Fourth message
2   NULL        1           Second message
```

I realize I could do this with a `union`, but I can't see any way of designing a union query without making it tremendously inefficient.

How would you solve such a problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Here's the table I'm working with:

```
create table message (
   id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
   parent_id int(11) unsigned default null,
   owner_id int(11) unsigned not null,
   message varchar(255) default null,

   index (parent_id),

   foreign key (parent_id) references message(id) on update cascade on delete cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the data you are starting with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join and a literal translation from the requirement will do.

```
select m.* from message m 
left join message p on m.parent_id=p.id
where m.owner_id=1 or p.owner_id=1
order by m.id
```

The above SQL selects messages whose owner id is 1 or whose parent's owner id is 1.

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db1361/1)

Comment: Well, I don't care about the owner ID of `p` here, I want the `owner_id` of the record of `p`'s `parent_id` to have `owner_id` 1.

Comment: You mean `m`'s `parent_id`? `p` is the parent.

Comment: But that's what you want right? Either the owner id of the message itself is `1`, or the owner id of the message's parent is `1`. Take another look at the query and see the example in the link.

Comment: Aah, yes. You are right. Sorry, I thought a bit backward. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want any message where either the parent or the owner is 1.  You then want to order this hierarchically.  Because you are looking for only a single id, I think this does what you want:

```
select m.*
from message m
where 1 in (m.id, m.parent_id)
order by coalesce(m.parent_id, m.id), id;
```

Comment: Well, the parent refers to the `id` in the same table, not the `owner_id`. A solution (but performance nightmare) using union would be: `select * from message where owner_id = 1 union select * from message where parent_id in (select id from message where owner_id = 1)`

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström . . . I think I figured that out between the `where` and the `order by`.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the following query with a union:

```
select id from message where owner_id="USER" --all the records for which the owner is directly "USER"
union all -- to remove duplicates generated by the union if any
select m1.id from message m1, message m2 where m1.parent_id=m2.parent_id and m1.id != m2.id and m2.owner_id="USER"
-- all the records from m2 that share the same parent_id as m1 (but that are not the same id to avoid taking the m1 record itself)
-- for which m2.owner is the specified one
```

Good luck! Cheers